# TYPO3 Fluid f:for each iterator

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have a simple question about the `f:for` ViewHelper in TYPO3 6.2

How is it possible to apply an offset to the iterator to start at index 2?

---

Example:

```
<f:for each="{facility.media}" as="media" iteration="iterator">


                             <!-- this index should start at 2-->
    <img src="..." data-lightbox-index="{ iterator.index }">


</f:for>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible.

You might do workarounds.
you can assign the needed value to a temporary variable. multiple possibilities:

- use `f:cycle` (only possible with few entries)
- use `ext:vhs` to create/assign the calculated value to a fluid-variable
- use `f:alias` to create a local fluid-variable inside your loop.

for the later two solutions you need the possibility to calculate, which is not given in fluid.
but you can use a typoscript viewhelper:

```
lib.calc = TEXT
lib.calc {
    current = 1
    prioriCalc = 1
}
```

and call it with `{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.calc',data:{iterator.index}+2)}`

```
<f:for each="{facility.media}" as="media" iteration="iterator">
    <f:alias map="{newIndex:'{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:\'lib.calc\',data:\'{iterator.index}+2\')}'}">
        <img src="..." data-lightbox-index="{newIndex}" />
    </f:alias>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an additional f:if

```
<f:for each="{facility.media}" as="media" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.index} > 2">
          <img src="..." data-lightbox-index="{ iterator.index }">
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `fluid ForViewHelper` like below.

Using Index and Index start always 0. So, you can do this like below condition.

```
<f:for each="{facility.media}" as="media" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.index} >= 2">
          <img src="..." data-lightbox-index="{ iterator.index }">
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Using Cycle and cycle always start with 1.

```
<f:for each="{facility.media}" as="media" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.cycle} >= 3">
          <img src="..." data-lightbox-index="{ iterator.index }">
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

For more [ForViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/ForViewHelper.html)

Comment: doesn't work. image 1 and image 2 wouldn't be displayed.